# I can't login to any of my WordPress development websites through the front end or WP-CLI

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, debian, wp-cli

Recently my WordPress sites started acting up on the login page.
When a user provides their credentials and hits enter, the page seems to reload.

No feedback is given when the site reloads. Not even a faulty password message.
When using the "recover lost password" option the page will ask for an email or username but then proceed to do the same thing that the login page does.

When running "wp user list" from the WP-CLI on any of the sites, this is the error message.

```
    WordPress database error Got error -1 from storage engine for query DELETE 
    FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = '_site_transient_security_report_performed_recently'
     made by include('phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php'), include
    ('phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/wp-cli.php'), WP_CLI\Runner->start, WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress, 
    require('phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/wp-settings-cli.php'), 
    do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, 
    Jetpack::perform_security_reporting, get_site_transient,
    delete_site_option, delete_network_option, delete_option
```

The server hosts many other WordPress sites and they are all doing this.

When a site is moved to our production server the login page works as it should.

This started out as a problem on only one site and has now spread to the whole server.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to MySQL command line interface or use the graphical client of your choice, and run

```
repair table wp_options;
```

If that does not fix it, drop the `wp_options` table and replace it with a working copy.

If that does not fix it, you will need to debug MySQL deeper starting by perusing the MySQL error log.